# does the vanishing of this determinant guarantee that 4 points lie on a circle or line?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, inverse

while seeking to devise an intuitive, computation-lite demonstration of the fact that inversion preserves the concyclicity or collinearity of four points in the complex plane, i hit on the following idea, which initially seemed promising:

let $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ be four distinct complex numbers, none of which is zero.

if we define the determinant:
$$
M=M(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=
\begin{vmatrix}
|z_1|^2 & \mathfrak{Re} z_1 & \mathfrak{Im}z_1 & 1 \\
|z_2|^2 & \mathfrak{Re} z_2 & \mathfrak{Im}z_2 & 1 \\
|z_3|^2 & \mathfrak{Re} z_3 & \mathfrak{Im}z_3 & 1 \\
|z_4|^2 & \mathfrak{Re} z_4 & \mathfrak{Im}z_4 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
then, since $|z^{-1}| = |z|^{-1}$, and $\mathfrak{Re} z^{-1}=\frac{\mathfrak{Re}z}{|z|^2},\mathfrak{Im} z^{-1}=-\frac{\mathfrak{Im}}{|z|^2}$  we have
$$
M^*=M(z_1^{-1},z_2^{-1},z_3^{-1},z_4^{-1}) = \frac{M(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)}{|z_1|^2 |z_2|^2|z_3|^2|z_4|^2}
$$
i.e. $M=0$ if and only if $M^*=0$

(i think) it is straightforward to show that if the four $z_i$ are concyclic or collinear, then the corresponding determinant is zero.

however, for this idea to have traction, the reverse implication is required, i.e. that if a determinant of this type is zero, then the four points are either concyclic or collinear.

**question** can anyone help? either by pointing out some glitch in my reasoning, or by supplying an argument for the reverse implication required to develop the proof-idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/599456/35416) I've demonstrated that this is the case. There I used real coordinates, not complex numbers, but that doesn't harm the argument.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation!